# Which algorithm should I use for car's head/tail light detection in FPGA

Tags: algorithm, fpga, surf

My project is to detect head/tail lights of cars from captured video and can be implemented on FPGA. I intend to use SURF algorithm, but I know it's a strong one. Moreover, my best FPGA kit is virtex 5. So is it possible to implement SURF or modified SURF on virtex 5? Or any simpler algorithm I could use?

Comment: You mean you want to implement the SURF algorithm inside and FPGA? Do you have any previous experience with FPGAs? Because this sounds loke a really big task even for an experienced guy.

Comment: That's true. cuz SURF and SIFT are really complicated so Im reading some papers of detecting headlights to find another way. If u guys got any suggestion, plz tell me

Comment: Well, this is not a trivial questions. You have to deal with multiple issues that are pretty hard to handle. The amount of data, the data flow, the algorithm itself just to mention a few. You might implement your algorithm in Mathlab and port it to an FPGA using their HDL coveter. Just do a quick search on internet,  I am sure you find some interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Why do you want to use an FPGA?](http://parallelpoints.com/why-use-an-fpga/)

I would first figure out how to do the (not trivial) problem of detecting car headlights in a more interactive environment than the FPGA simulation/synthesis chain!

Comment: Indeed, prototype on a computer in your language of choice. Once you have the algorithm down, port it to the FPGA.